# Problemas al momento de mostrar mi subcategoria

Tags: php, array

[image: Quiero mostrar la subcategoria con <H4> y la lista con <li>]

Quiero mostrar la subcategoria con  y la lista con

Me sale error en la muestra del array

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Te recomiendo el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para mejorar el formato de tu pregunta. Por favor prefiere compartir código como texto formateado con `CTRL-K` en cez de captura de pantalla. Si se trata de errores, ayuda de especificar precisamente que error te causa problemas.

Comment: A primera vista parece que `$idFirsLevel["id"]` no es un arreglo.

Answer (score 0):

La consulta de la línea 25 falla porque el `'...IN ('".$base."')...'` debe contener una serie de valores separados por comas dentro del paréntesis, tipo `(1,2,3,4)`, y estás incluyendo un string que proviene de hacer un `implode` separado por `" "` en lugar de `","`.

`$base` es un string ya que lo rellenas con una cadena al hacer el `implode`, no un array, no pongas `$base[]`.

Prueba con estos cambios.

Añadido a la respuesta: lo que faltaba por corregir es que el implode hay que hacerlo después del foreach, cuando ya se tiene el array de datos, no mientras se añaden los elementos.

```
$data = array ();
foreach ($resultado as $elemento) {
  $data[] = $elemento["id"];
}
$string = implode (",",$data);
```

Comment: estuvo bueno esa correccion gracias por el apoyo, me puedes ayudar con un error en mostrar el ID

Comment: El error "Illegal string offset" indica que estas intentando usar como array un string, haz un var_dump($mi_variable) de las variables donde te aparece el error para comprobar que efectivamente tienes un array y que dicho array tiene un valor asignado a 'id'.

Comment: no entiendo como lo relaciono por que esta separado las variables y este es un array que llamo desde una funcion que esta conectada con una base de datos. Ayudame

Comment: Hola que tal, hice lo que me dijiste con un var_dump($s) para mostrar mi array y si me muestra, si me aparece entonces el error seria en el 'id' y eso a que se debería, ayúdame por favor.

Answer (score 0):

[image: implode error]

Hice los cambios que me dijiste yo también lo intente, igual me sale el error quee estoy implementando mal el implode o bien en el arreglo ó string.

Comment: Si lo que hace es reemplazar el implode, creo que acabo de ver el error, hago una edición de la respuesta.

Comment: foreach (get_second_level_categories() as $categorySecondLevel) {
  if($s['id'] == $categorySecondLevel['id']){
  $title = true; ?>
     <?php
         }
      }                                                                                                                       TENGO UN ERROR ( Illegal string offset 'id' in ) NO ENTIENDO ME AYUDAS POR FAVOR